# Is there a way to search but exclude questions with a certain tag?

Tags: support, tags, spoilers, search

I am currently reading A Song of Ice and Fire (just finished CoK) and I am really scared that I will accidentally read a question title that will spoil something really big for me.  Is there a way to exclude a particular tag from your search results?

Comment: I think if you do something like `-[tagname]`, you exclude questions with that tag from search.

Comment: What @alexwlchan said is correct. For example, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars+-star-wars-legends is a search for [star-wars] without any [star-wars-legends].

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Dupe-closing this since I've now posted a definitive proposed-FAQ question about the search facility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes: use a minus sign.

Searching for `[a-song-of-ice-and-fire]` gives you all questions with that tag; searching for `[a-song-of-ice-and-fire] -[a-storm-of-swords]` will give you all questions tagged with the first tag but not the second.

However, **be warned**: not all questions that concern material from *A Storm of Swords* will be tagged as such! If you want to avoid spoilers altogether, you'll be better off setting the entire [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) tag (and [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) for good measure) on [ignore](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/51142).

> And if you see anything about the Red Wedding or the Purple Wedding, read no further!

Comment: I refuse to click on that...although I don't think you'd be that mean.

Comment: @CHEESE Ha! :->